# React Jest code coverage of service execution (mock Axios call)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

React Jest code coverage of service execution (mock Axios call)

I am new to React and Jest. I want to test the below line of code using Jest.

I want to check if callback, dispatch, clearMessage, errMessage, and service are getting executed or not.
Or want to check if the service can return with mock data?

```
export const loadUsersData = ({requId, dataId, callback, dispatch, clearMessage, errMessage, service}) => {
    const reqObj = {requId, dataId};
    dispatch(clearMessage());
    service.fetchUsers(reqObj).then((response) => {
        const accData = response?.data?.accNumbers ? response.data.accNumbers : [];
        if(accData.length) {
            return callback(accData);
       } else {
            dispatch(errMessage("No data found"));
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        dispatch(errMessage("Service failed to load data"));
        return callback(accData);
    });
}
```

Note :- service.fetchUsers makes Axios call to fetch data from the server.

I want to cover the above lines of code and improve the percentage of code coverage.

```
it("fetch data", async()={
    const reqObj = {requId:"123", dataId:"ABC"};
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    const clearMessage = jest.fn();
    const errMessage = jest.fn();
    const service = {fetchUsers : jest.fn()}
    loadUsersData = ({requId:"123", dataId:"ABC", callback, dispatch, clearMessage, errMessage, service});
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(service.fetchUsers).toHaveBeenCalledWith(reqObj);
});
```

I tried above test case. But it didn't work. I tried

jest.spyOn(service, "fetchUsers").mockResolvedValue({mockData});
But it throws below error.

at ModuleMocker.spyOn (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:774:16)

Comment: What's the question? Does your test work?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understood your ask correctly.I assume you want to manipulate response and cover all lines of codes.

You can try to spy the method and pass response as your conditions fulfil

```
import * as service from '{service file}';

jest.spyOn(service, "fetchUsers").mockResolvedValue({ [PASS RESPONSE DATA TO COVER THEN BOLCK] });


jest.spyOn(service, "fetchUsers").mockRejectedValue({ [PASS RESPONSE DATA TO COVER ERROR BOLCK] });
```

Comment: jest.spyOn(service, "fetchUsers").mockResolvedValue({a:1});

When I use above line of code, it show below error.


at ModuleMocker.spyOn (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:774:16)

Comment: try to mock file before your test `describe`  jest.mock({service file path}); after that you can spy function on that file

Comment: eg: jest.mock('../service.ts')

Comment: Do you have any specific example which will satisfy above scenario. Can you please code snippet?